# Letter Combinations of a Phone Number (Java) - Passing an array through functions

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

**Problem**

Given a digit string, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent. (Check out your cellphone to see the mappings) Input:Digit string "23", Output: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"]

**Question**

I'm confused about the solution code below from [LeetCode](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/leetcode-letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number-java/). Why does passing the `result` array through recursive calls change the `result` array in `letterCombinations`? Is it because the result array in ever recursive `getString` call is referencing the same result array?

```
public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(2, "abc");
    map.put(3, "def");
    map.put(4, "ghi");
    map.put(5, "jkl");
    map.put(6, "mno");
    map.put(7, "pqrs");
    map.put(8, "tuv");
    map.put(9, "wxyz");
    map.put(0, "");

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (digits == null || digits.length() == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    ArrayList<Character> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    getString(digits, temp, result, map);

    return result;
}

public void getString(String digits, ArrayList<Character> temp, ArrayList<String> result,
        HashMap<Integer, String> map) {
    if (digits.length() == 0) {
        char[] arr = new char[temp.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = temp.get(i);
        }
        result.add(String.valueOf(arr));
        return;
    }

    Integer curr = Integer.valueOf(digits.substring(0, 1));
    String letters = map.get(curr);
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
        temp.add(letters.charAt(i));
        getString(digits.substring(1), temp, result, map);
        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @slim do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: Yes, `result` is the same reference to the arraylist that's passed down the recursive chain.

Comment: You are correct in "`getString` call is referencing the same result array". Basically you are passing a reference to the result array thus any changes that happen throughout the recursion, happen to the actual array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it because the result array in ever recursive `getString` call is referencing the same result array?**

The answer is **yes**.

**Why does passing the `result` array through recursive calls change the `result` array in letterCombinations?**

The passing of an array `result` in `letterCombinations` changes the array and `getString` call is referencing the same result array. As it is a recursive method call, it gets upadtes after each iteration and stores the value to the same reference. That is the main reason, why you have different values for each iteration or a recursive call. Thus it affects the actual array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'll point out that despite the name of the site you got it from, this isn't especially clear code.

The call to `getString()` has three changing parameters - `digits`, `temp` and `result`.

`map` never changes - it would be better and clearer if it were a constant. Let's pretend it is, so the signature of `getString()` is `getString(String digits, List<Character> temp`.

The naming isn't obvious, but `temp` contains the "work done so far", so the first time we call it, it's an empty list.

Let's look at what happens the first time it is called, with `digits == 234` and `temp` an empty list:

- `digits.length() != 0` -- so we skip the whole of the first block.
- we grab the first digit, `2` and look up its letters in the map - `"a"`
- we loop through the letters:

  - we put `'a'` onto the end of `temp`, making `temp == ['a']`
  - then we call `getString("34", ['a'])`
  - we remove the last item from `temp`, making `temp == []`
  - then the same with `'b'` -- `getString("34",['b'])`
  - then the same with `'c'` -- `getString("34",['c'])`

Then we're done. But what happened in those recursive calls?

Follow the logic through `getString("34",['a'])` and you'll see how it grabs `3` from its local `digits` and makes calls like `getString("4", ['a','d'])`.

In turn `getString("4", ['a','d'])` makes calls like `getString("",['a','d','g'])`.

Finally we're at level where the recursion stops. Look at what happens when we call `getString("",['a','d','g'])`:

- `digits.length == 0`, so we go into the `if` block and return -- we don't progress into the part that would call `getString()` again.
- we (in a bit of a laborious way) join the chars from `temp` into a `String`, and add it to `result`.
- And that's it.

Better code:

```
 if(digits.isEmpty()) {
     result.add(String.join("",temp));
     return;
 }
```

We have never created a new `result` - we're just passing the same one (and the same `map` too) to every invocation of `getString()`. So when one `getString()` adds an item, that item's still there when the next `getString()` adds a second.

---

Recursive methods can usually be read as:

```
 def recursivemethod(params) {
      if(it's a no-brainer) {
          output an answer
      } else {
          do a little bit of the job
          call recursiveMethod(newParams)
      }
 }
```

In this case, it's a no-brainer when `digits` is empty -- the whole of the answer is in `temp` and just needs adding to the result list.

If it's not a no-brainer, the "little bit of the job" is to handle the first digit, recursing for each possible letter it could represent.

---

Cleaner in my opinion, while maintaining the spirit of the original:

```
private static final Map<Character, String> DECODINGS = new HashMap<>();
static {
    DECODINGS.put('2', "abc");
    // <snip>
}

public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    addCombinationsToList(digits, "", result);
    return result;
}

private void addCombinationsToList(String digits, String prefix, List<String> list) {
    if (digits.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(prefix);
    } else {
        String letters = DECODINGS.get(digits.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            addCombinationsToList(digits.substring(1), prefix + letters.charAt(i), list);
        }
    }
}
```

By building an immutable string `prefix + letters.charAt(i)` rather than manipulating a mutable `List<Character>`, you avoid having to put it back the way you found it, making code that's much easier to understand.

Comment: Note that this is not an efficient approach to the actual problem - for example when processing `getString("2345", [ ])` it does all the work to calculate the expansions of `345` three times, even though it'll be the same result each time.